# Big O Analysis for Algorithm

Tags: c#, big-o

Next in my series of Big O questions that I can't find the answer to

Take the following example

```
for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
{
    for(int j = i; j < someNumber; j++)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Would this still be considered O(n^2)? I only ask because I feel that this has to be less that O(n^2), since the inner loop is executing less and less for every iteration of i (since j is starting closer and closer to someNumber).

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is such a bad homework question. You can at least tell the OP has thought about it for a few minutes.

Comment: I've graduated a few years ago. This isn't homework. This is a legitimate question regarding a misunderstanding I have about how to compute the time complexity of this class of algorithm

Comment: @jbutler483 This is far from "do my homework for me", OP showed some legitimate thought and effort to solve the problem and asked a perfectly good question.

Comment: it will be executed n*(n+1)/2 times. So still `O(N^2)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The outer loop runs n times. The inner loop starts out running n times, but decreases with each iteration of the outer loop, until the last iteration where it only runs once. The code inside the inner loop will run

n + (n−1) + ... + 2 + 1

times.

That can be simplified to n(n + 1)/2 ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260)), or n<sup>2</sup>/2 + n/2, or finally  (n<sup>2</sup> + n) / 2.  Since the first term is n<sup>2</sup>, the algorithm is in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: That proof was exactly what I needed to understand this. Thank you!